# xdotool key ctrl+W wrecks my machine

Tags: linux, xdotools

Whenever I'm running the command `xdotool key ctrl+W` in terminal (Arch Linux), it closes all its tabs and my Chromium app too, and I can only recover from it with reset button (can't reopen terminal, as if it's endlessly pressing ctrl-W).

Does anyone understand this strange behaviour? How can it be properly handled?